# restcomm call between webRTC client and a normal SIP client ends with 480 message

Tags: webrtc, sip, telecommunication, transcode, restcomm

I'm trying to setup a call between webRTC based client (olympus) and a standard one (x-lite i.e.). 
The call is failing (480). I believe it is because of SDP negotiation failed.
Currently I use standard telestax mediaserver setup.

Can restcomm be configured in a way, that it transcodes the stream (and modifies codec negotiation), so webRTC based clients can call the standard sip ones ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Hubert

Comment: Can you provide more information, like RestComm logs messages or configuration details?

Comment: I made a workarund for that.
I created a simple application in RVD, that simple dial the sip URI of another SIP proxy. In such way restcomm seems to transcode the connection, and it works properly.

Comment: Hi yes flow work from webRTC client -> RVD -> Sip Client. but how can we do it from a Sip Client -> RVD App -> webRTC